# How do I reference X1, X2, X3 after an rbind operation

Tags: r

I used RBIND to stack 3 datasets no column names:  `combined <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)`

It worked fine.

It assigned X1, X2 and X3 to the columns.

I renamed the columns using:

```
names(combineddf)[names(combineddf)=="X1"] <- "date"
```

I used `head(combineddf)` to verify it worked.  I see the new "date" name.

But where I reference "date" I get an error.

When I do `str(combineddf)` I still see X1, X2 X3.

How do I fix this, and why is R doing this?

Comment: How did you *'reference "date"'*? What was the error you got? *"When I do str(combineddf) I still see X1, X2 X3"* That doesn't sound right. If the `head()` verification worked, then the `str()` verification should be in alignment. Are you sure you don't have two copies of this data with slightly different names or something? Or maybe you re-ran earlier lines of code and didn't also run the name reassignment?

Comment: `date` will not be an object in its own right. So saying you "referenced "date" suggests you should instead have been "referencing" `combineddf$date` or perhaps `combined$date` since you used two different names.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: happy to include an example but it is reading a csv.

Comment: If it helps, the STR shows:  - attr(*, "spec")=
  .. cols(
  ..   X1 = col_character(),
  ..   X2 = col_character(),
  ..   X3 = col_character(),
  ..   X4 = col_character()
  .. )
 - attr(*, "problems")=<externalptr>

Comment: right now, I solved it by exporting a csv, reading it back into R, and using the original renaming code.  Hoping for something a little easier.